# Maven failed to parse POMs at Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-3, jenkins-pipeline, maven-plugin

I am getting the artifact in my remote repository after deploying but still I'm getting error in the build "Failed to parse POMs"

Could you please help me what is the mistake I've done. This is very basic maven project which I tried to pull the code from GitHub and trying to build and deploy the jar file in Nexus repository. Since its deploying the code in nexus once we run the job but still I'm getting error in Jenkins.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.560 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-11T08:02:36Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/pom.xml to com.indmax.app/helloworld/3.1-SNAPSHOT/helloworld-3.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/target/helloworld-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.indmax.app/helloworld/3.1-SNAPSHOT/helloworld-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/; will archive in a separate pass
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/target/helloworld-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/; will archive in a separate pass
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/pom.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1991)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It's weird for me that jenkins search pom.xml file in path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/pom.xml. I think it should be /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/pom.xml

Comment: Is it because of any job config issue ? I gave the path for pom file as "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo_maven/helloworld/pom.xml"

Comment: Are you sure that helloworld directory should be exist in path to pom.xml?

Comment: Yes that's the correct path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was trying with the wrong command in maven plugins.

```
mvn clean deploy
```

The issue with mvn command. The logic is we are executing the command in maven plugin and the prefix makes the build fail. Hence I figured out and it works with

```
clean deploy
```

Thanks!